# Impossibility of nontrivial product of vectors

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, vector-spaces

When introducing the tensor product of vectors, Serge Winitzki in his work *Linear Algebra via Exterior Products* claims that

> It turns out to be impossible to define a nontrivial product of vectors in a general vector space, such that the result is again a vector in the same space.

I can assume that he means a *bilinear* product here.  In the footer on that page he says

> The impossibility of this is proved in abstract algebra but I do not know the proof.

I forgot to look this up when I was reading through Dr. Winitzki's book, and perusing through the book, again, I realize that I've still never seen the proof.

Does someone know of a reference where I can see the proof of this claim?

Comment: It depends on what one means by "product". Brown and Gray classified the so-called cross products, in all (finite) dimensions (at least over $\Bbb R$). See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185991/is-the-vector-cross-product-only-defined-for-3d/462895#462895 If this is a satisfactory interpretation of "product", let me know and I'll write up a proper answer with a reference/link later tonight.

Comment: Based on the language he used before the above quote I'm led to believe that Winitzki used the word *product* to mean a binary operation that's linear in each argument.  On the other hand, that answer looks very interesting and I'm going to read through Brown and Gray's "Vector Cross Products" and couple of other papers I found referencing that paper today to learn more.  So thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found my comment useful! I'm not sure that what Winitzki means, as the map $(X, Y) \to X$ is a perfectly good nontrivial bilinear map $\Bbb V \times \Bbb V \to \Bbb V$. So, one really needs some stronger hypotheses if one wants to get nonexistence for most (say, f.d.) vector spaces. (Incidentally, there are nontrivial binary cross products in only two dimensions, namely, $3$ and $7$, and these are connected with the quaternions and octonions, resp.)

Comment: I'm also dubious of the statement. Take your favorite field $K$ and let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional $K$-vector space. Identifying $V$ with $K[x]/(x^n)$ certainly defines a product on $V$. You can define a whole lot of other algebra structures by identifying $V\cong K[x]/(f)$ for a degree $n$ polynomial $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret the claim to be about *natural* maps

$$V \otimes V \to V$$

(where natural means at the very least $GL(V)$-equivariant). This follows from the fact that $V \otimes V$ decomposes as a $GL(V)$ representation into a direct sum $S^2(V) \oplus \Lambda^2(V)$; these are irreps and neither of them are isomorphic to $V$ as an irrep, so the only $GL(V)$-equivariant map $S^2(V) \oplus \Lambda(V) \to V$ is the zero map.

Comment: This seems like a valid interpretation.  Accepted.

Comment: A stronger version of "natural" would mean a natural transformation between two functors $\text{Vect} \to \text{Vect}$ and that is even more impossible. By contrast, the exterior product is natural in this stronger sense.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Could you provide a hint on why no natural transformation $\otimes \Rightarrow \operatorname{Id}_{Vect}$ can exist?