# Cross product between two n-dimensional vector $(n = 4-5)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, cross-product

As we know, we can write the cross product between two three dimensional vectors as a matrix-vector product.

Let two vectors are 
$V = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
V_1 \\
V_2 \\
V_3 \end{array} \right] \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 1}$,

$V^0 = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
V_1^0 \\
V_2^0 \\
V_3^0 \end{array} \right] \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 1}$,

Then, we can write the cross product between both vector as matrix-vector product:
$V^0 \times V = 
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -V_3^0 & V_2^0\\
V_3^0 & 0 & -V_1^0\\
-V_2^0 & -V_1^0 & 0 \end{array} \right] .
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
V_1 \\
V_2 \\
V_3 \end{array} \right]$

However, if we consider general n-dimensional vectors (n = 4-5), could we still write it as dot product between a known vector V0 and unknown vector V?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. The cross product in not defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n \neq 3$.

Comment: related [Is the vector cross product only defined for 3D?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185991/is-the-vector-cross-product-only-defined-for-3d)

Comment: You can get something similar in $\mathbb{R}^7$, but it doesn't have all the same properties as the cross product.