# Cross product in higher dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality, multilinear-algebra, cross-product

Suppose we have a vector $(a,b)$ in $2$-space. Then the vector $(-b,a)$ is orthogonal to the one we started with. Furthermore, the function $$(a,b) \mapsto (-b,a)$$ is linear.

Suppose instead we have two vectors $x$ and $y$ in $3$-space. Then the cross product gives us a new vector $x \times y$ that's orthogonal to the first two. Furthermore, cross products are bilinear.

> **Question.** Can we do this in higher dimensions? For example, is there a way of turning three vectors in $4$-space into a fourth vector, orthogonal to the others, in a trilinear way?

Comment: You might want to look at the Gram Schmitt method here :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Comment: This construction has nothing to do with cross product, just happen to coincide in dimension 3.

Comment: A search for "generalized cross product" turns up a number of questions likely to be of interest, including [Is the vector cross product only defined for 3D?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185991) and [Generalized Cross Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752774). ;) (Not marking as a duplicate because you're better able to judge which question, if any, most nearly matches yours.)

Comment: You might be interested in the notion of the _orthogonal complement_. It can give you the vector orthogonal to a given set of $n-1$ independent vectors in $n$-space, like you're asking for $n=4$. But it can also give you $k$ independent vectors orthogonal to a given set of $n-k$ independent vectors in $n$-space. So you can take two vectors in 4-space and find two vectors perpendicular to them _and_ to each other.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-dimensional_cross_product ​ ​

Comment: But in the plane, there are three cross products: $$\begin{align} (a,b) \times (x,y) & = a y-b x & c \times (x,y) & = (-c y, c x) & (a,b) \times z & = (b z,-a z) \end{align}$$

Comment: You may also be interested in this generalization question, posted by Terry Tao on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/314613/28209

Comment: @MarkS., awesome thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes. It is just like in dimension $3$: if your vectors are $(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4)$, $(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4)$, and $(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$, compute the formal determinant:$$\begin{vmatrix}t_1&t_2&t_3&t_4\\u_1&u_2&u_3&u_4\\v_1&v_2&v_3&v_4\\e_1&e_2&e_3&e_4\end{vmatrix}.$$ You then see $(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4)$ as the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Then the previous determinant is $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4)$ with\begin{align*}\alpha_1&=t_4u_3v_2-t_3u_4v_2-t_4u_2v_3+t_2u_4v_3+t_3u_2v_4-t_2u_3v_4\\\alpha_2&=-t_4u_3v_1+t_3u_4v_1+t_4u_1v_3-t_1u_4v_3-t_3u_1v_4+t_1u_3v_4\\\alpha_3&=t_4u_2v_1-t_2u_4v_1-t_4u_1v_2+t_1u_4v_2+t_2u_1v_4-t_1u_2v_4\\\alpha_4&=-t_3u_2v_1+t_2u_3v_1+t_3u_1v_2-t_1u_3v_2-t_2u_1v_3+t_1u_2v_3\end{align*}It's a vector orthogonal to the other three.

---

I followed a suggestion taken from the comments on this answer: to put the entries $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$, and $e_4$ at the bottom. It makes no difference in odd dimension, but it produces the natural sign in even dimension.

Following another suggestion, I would like to add this remark:$$\alpha_1=-\begin{vmatrix}t_2&t_3&t_4\\u_2&u_3&u_4\\v_2&v_3&v_4\end{vmatrix}\text{, }\alpha_2=\begin{vmatrix}t_1&t_3&t_4\\u_1&u_3&u_4\\v_1&v_3&v_4\end{vmatrix}\text{, }\alpha_3=-\begin{vmatrix}t_1&t_2&t_4\\u_1&u_2&u_4\\v_1&v_2&v_4\end{vmatrix}\text{ and }\alpha_4=\begin{vmatrix}t_1&t_2&t_3\\u_1&u_2&u_3\\v_1&v_2&v_3\\\end{vmatrix}.$$

Comment: Very lucid and appreciable answer.thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure the row of basis vectors should be on the bottom to get the right-handedness correct; only in odd dimensions can this row be moved to the top without a change in sign whilst keeping the vectors in the same order.

Comment: (+1) This is the method I've used in a few answers. The formula is easy to remember!

Comment: @lastresort Nice remark. I shall edit my answer taking that into account.

Comment: Is $$\alpha_1 ={\rm det} \left| \matrix{ t_2 & t_3 & t_4 \\ u_2 & u_3 & u_4 \\ v_2 & v_3 & v_4} \right| $$ and so on?

Comment: @ja72 No; it's the symmetric of that.

Comment: Can you please edit the answer and explain the rule for getting $\alpha_i$?

Comment: @ja72 It's done.

Comment: To get even a shorter notation, one could use the levi-civita tensor in $n$-dimensions. For ex. in a 3-vector product in 4 dimensions would have the component $i$ written as

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think one could use the levi-civita tensor in $n$-dimensions to get a shorter notation. For ex. a 3-vector product in 4 dimensions would have the component $i$ written as $ v_i= \varepsilon_{ijkl}A_jB_kC_l$, where Einstein notation is being used. $\varepsilon_{1234}=1$, it is invariant to cyclic permutations.  A further property is $\varepsilon_{ijkl}=-\varepsilon_{jikl}$. When neighboring indices are exchanged, there appears a minus sign. This implies that a tensor element with repeated indices is 0.

Comment: @minimax I can't correct (or agree with) you, because I know nothing about the Lavi-Civita tensor.

Comment: Look here then: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol

Answer (score 24):

My answer is in addition to José's and Antinous's answers but maybe somewhat more abstract. In principle, their answers are using coordinates, whereas I'm trying to do it coordinate-free.

What you are looking for is the wedge or exterior product.
The exterior power $\bigwedge^k(V)$ of some vector space $V$ is the quotient of the tensor product $\bigotimes^k(V)$ by the relation $v\otimes v$.
To be somewhat more concrete and less abstract, this just means that for any vector $v\in V$ the wedge product $v\wedge v=0\in\bigwedge^2(V)$. Whenever you wedge vectors together, the result equals zero if at least two of the factors are linearly dependent.
Think of what happens to the cross product in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

In fact, let $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n$ be a basis of an inner product space $V$. Then $e_{i_1}\wedge e_{i_2}\wedge \ldots \wedge e_{i_k}$ is a basis for $\bigwedge^k(V)$ where $1\leq i_1 < i_2 < \ldots < i_k\leq n$.

If $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ then $v \wedge w$ equals $v \times w$ up to signs of the entries. This seems a bit obscure because technically $v\wedge w$ should be an element of $\bigwedge^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$. However, the latter vector space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$. In fact, this relation is true for all exterior powers given an orientation on the vector space.
The isomorphism is called the  [Hodge star operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual#Formal_definition_of_the_Hodge_star_of_k-vectors).
It says that there is an isomorphism $\star\colon\bigwedge^{n-k}(V)\to\bigwedge^{k}(V)$. This map operates on a $(n-k)$-wedge $\beta$ via the relation
$$
  \alpha \wedge \beta = \langle \alpha,\star\beta \rangle \,\omega
$$
where $\alpha\in\bigwedge^{k}(V)$, $\omega\in\bigwedge^n(V)$ is an orientation form on $V$ and $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is the induced inner product on $\bigwedge^{k}(V)$ (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Inner_product)). Notice that the wiki-page defines the relation the other way around.

How does all this answer your question you ask?
Well, let us take $k=1$ and $V=\mathbb{R}^n$. Then the Hodge star isomorphism identifies the spaces $\bigwedge^{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\bigwedge^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\mathbb{R}^n$. This is good because you originally wanted to say something about orthogonality between a set of $n-1$ linearly indepedent vectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{n-1}$ and their "cross product".
Now let us exactly do that and set $\beta :=v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge v_{n-1}\in\bigwedge^{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Then the image $\star\beta = \star(v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge v_{n-1})$ is a regular vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the defining condition above implies for $\alpha=v_i\in\mathbb{R}^n=\bigwedge^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$
$$
  v_i \wedge (v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge v_{n-1}) = \alpha \wedge \beta = \langle \alpha,\star\beta \rangle \,\omega = \langle v_i,\star\beta \rangle \,\omega.
$$
However, the left hand side equals zero for $i=1,2,\ldots,n-1$, so that the vector $\star\beta$ is orthogonal to all vectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{n-1}$ which is what you asked for. So you might want to define the cross product of $n-1$ vectors as $v_1 \times v_2 \times \ldots \times v_{n-1} := \star(v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge v_{n-1})$.

Maybe keep in mind that the other two answers implicitly use the Hodge star operation (and also a basis) to compute the "cross product in higher dimension" through the formal determinant which is encoded in the use of the wedge product here.

Comment: So concretely, how do we actually know what the hodge star of a $k$-blade is? For example, work in $4$-space with the standard orientation. Suppose we want to know $\star(v_1 \wedge v_3).$ If I understand correctly, it's either $v_2 \wedge v_4$ or else $v_4 \wedge v_2$. How do we know which one?

Comment: It depends on the orientation that you choose for your vector space.
Let's say $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ form an oriented basis for $V$ (that is, $\omega = v_1\wedge v_2\wedge v_3\wedge v_4$) then $\star(v_1\wedge v_3)=v_4\wedge v_2$. This can be seen using the defining relation for $\alpha=v_i\wedge v_j$ cycling through all possible combinations $(i,j)$. This is what they say on the wiki-page linked above in the section "Computation of the Hodge star" albeit expressed a little bit complicated in my opinion.

Comment: Of all combinations $(i,j)$ only $(2,4)$ and $(4,2)$ remain (because otherwise the left hand side equals zero). Then you assume $\star(v_1\wedge v_3)=v_k\wedge v_l$ and think about which combinations for $(k,l)$ remain on the right hand side of the def. relation. Then you will see that the only possible one is $(k,l)=(4,2)$. To see the last part, look at the definition of the induced scalar product on $\bigwedge^2(V)$.

Comment: And also, as I forgot to mention this, $v_2\wedge v_4=-v_4\wedge v_2$. Changing the position of two vectors in a $k$-wedge just changes the sign. So really it only depends on the chosen orientation (or "right-handedness") of your vector space.

Comment: Is $\Lambda^2 \textbf{R}^3$ _canonically_ isomorphic to $\textbf{R}^3$, or just isomorphic?

Comment: @étale-cohomology The hodge star depends on a choice of inner product and orientation. So it is not canonical. I don't think that you can identify them canonically.

Comment: Honestly, I don't really get the definition $$\alpha \wedge \beta = \langle \alpha,\star \beta\rangle \omega.$$ For instance, suppose we're working in $3$-space. Suppose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are $1$-vectors. Then $\alpha \wedge \beta$ is a $2$-vector, while the RHS, being a scaled vesion of $\omega$, seems to be a $3$-vector. What am I not understanding?

Comment: Check my edit in the last section of the answer. Maybe that clears things up? Basically, $\alpha$ is a $k$-vector whereas $\beta$ is an $(n-k)$-vector. Admittedly, the hodge star should better have an index $k$, so that you know which spaces it maps to and from. I guess this is usually omitted for notational brevity.

Comment: I see. And I guess this can equivalently be written $\alpha \wedge \star \beta = \langle \alpha ,\beta\rangle \omega$, with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ both $k$-vectors, which is how wikipedia does it.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that $$\alpha \wedge \beta = \langle \alpha,\beta\rangle \omega \rightarrow \beta = \star \alpha$$ is true for all $k$-vectors $\alpha$ and all $(n-k)$-vectors $\beta$?

Comment: For example, work in $2$-space and let $\omega = x \wedge y$. Would it be fair to say that since $x \wedge y = \langle x, y\rangle \omega$, hence $y = \star x$?

Comment: Sorry, my notation was a bit obscure in the previous question; by $x$ I meant $(1,0)$ and by $(0,1)$.

Comment: Yes, it can be written the way wikipedia does it by using the inverse of my star operator. I added a note to my answer. I chose the definition above because the last section of my answer reads more easily that way. 
No, you cannot do what you propose because your equation is false since $\langle x,y\rangle=0$. You want to find $\star y$, such that $x\wedge y=\langle x,\star y\rangle \omega$ where here $x,y$ are positively oriented and thus $\omega=x\wedge y$. Therefore the only possibility for the value of the factor $\langle x,\star y\rangle$ is $1$. Hence, $\star y =x$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62884/discussion-between-sven-pistre-and-goblin).

Answer (score 14):

You can work out the cross product $p$ in $n$-dimensions using the following:

$$p=\det\left(\begin{array}{lllll}e_1&x_1&y_1&\cdots&z_1\\e_2&x_2&y_2&\cdots&z_2\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\e_n&x_n&y_n&\cdots&z_n\end{array}\right),$$
where $\det$ is the formal determinant of the matrix, the $e_i$ are the base vectors (e.g. $\hat{i},\hat{j},\hat{k}$, etc), and $x,y,\ldots,z$ are the $n-1$ vectors you wish to "cross".

You will find that $x\cdot p=y\cdot p=\cdots=z\cdot p=0$.

It's wonderful the determinant produces a vector with this property.

Comment: Are there any requirements on the basis vectors $e_1, ..., e_n$? Like, do they need to form an orthonormal basis, or something?

Comment: Yeah but do they have to be? Can't we take any other basis?

Comment: By changing the basis to $\widetilde e_i$ you will have to change the vector entries to the coefficients $\widetilde x_i$ in the basis expansion for the new basis. 
Remember that the above is only a formal determinant as this is not actually a matrix (since the first column consists of entries that are vectors themselves).
So it does not matter if the basis is orthonormal or not but you will have to adjust your formal determinant formula.

Comment: (+1) This is the logical extension of José Carlos Santos' answer to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (at first, this is what I thought he had given, but now I see his only covers $\mathbb{R}^4$).

Comment: @robjohn I actually posted my answer 2 minutes before he did :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and apart from other answers an interesting approach to think about it is using Clifford's algebra.

This can introduce you the basic concept in a nonrigorous but approachable manner.

https://slehar.wordpress.com/2014/03/18/clifford-algebra-a-visual-introduction/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however that article is extremely long and it's difficult to find a Clifford-style answer to my question by reading through it. Can I ask you to write up some details on how to compute an actual cross product using Clifford approach's?