# Is there a reasonable generalization of the formula $|x\times y|^2+|x\bullet y|^2 = |x|^2|y|^2$ to higher dimensions?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, we can take both dot products and cross products. These are related by the formula $$|x\times y|^2+|x\bullet y|^2 = |x|^2|y|^2,$$ which tells you the the length of one in terms of the length of the other. This formula follows from: $$|x \times y| = |x||y|\sin \theta_{x,y}, \qquad |x \bullet y| = |x||y||\cos \theta_{x,y}|$$

Suppose we want to generalize to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n > 3$. We can still take dot products of pairs of vectors, and it's still true that $$|x \bullet y| = |x||y||\cos \theta_{x,y}|,$$ almost by definition. But since the [higher-dimensional cross product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371022/cross-product-in-higher-dimensions) requires more than $2$ inputs, there aren't any obvious formulae involving it that might be true. I was thinking that perhaps we can use wedge products instead. And, I've been gazing at the wikipedia article on [Clifford algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra) trying to find something relevant, but to no avail.

(I don't really understand Clifford algebras...)

Anyway:

> **Question.** Is there a reasonable generalization of the formula $|x\times y|^2+|x\bullet y|^2 = |x|^2|y|^2$ to higher dimensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is
$$|x|^2|y|^2=(x\cdot y)^2+|x\wedge y|^2.$$
But here $x\wedge y$ is an element of the exterior square $\bigwedge^2\Bbb R^n$. If $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ is the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$
then $e_1\wedge e_2,e_1\wedge e_3,\ldots,e_1\wedge e_n, e_2\wedge e_3,
\ldots,e_{n-1}\wedge e_n$ is a orthonormal basis of  $\bigwedge^2\Bbb R^n$.

We have the relations $u\wedge u=0$ and $u\wedge v=-v\wedge u$.

Comment: I see. And I guess the formula $|x \wedge y| = |x||y| \sin \theta_{x,y}$ is still true at this level of generality?