# Is the length of the multilinear cross product given by this formula? If not, what is the correct formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra, cross-product

This is an attempt to make [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388765/is-there-a-reasonable-generalization-of-the-formula-x-times-y2x-bullet-y?noredirect=1&lq=1) question more specific.

We can compute the length of the cross product in $\mathbb{R}^3$ using the formula:
$$|x\times y| = \sqrt{|x|^2|y|^2 - |x\cdot y|^2}$$

This makes sense for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and has a [geometric meaning](https://mathinsight.org/cross_product); it's the area of the parallelogram spanned by $x$ and $y$.

There's also a [higher-dimensional version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371022/cross-product-in-higher-dimensions?noredirect=1#comment6182388_2371022). For example, if $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^4$, there's a natural way of getting an orthogonal vector, that we might as well denote $x \times y \times z$. It should be understood that the function $\Box \times \Box \times \Box$ is a ternary operator, and cannot be refactored as $(\Box \times \Box) \times \Box$ or anything like that.

Anyway, I'd like to know if there's a similar formula for higher-dimensional cross products, perhaps of the form
$$|x \times y \times z| = \sqrt{\mathrm{something}}$$

It seems reasonable to conjecture that this is the square root of the determinant of the corresponding [Gramian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix). In particular, it seems reasonable to expect that $$|x \times y \times z| = \sqrt{\det([x,y,z]^\top [x,y,z])}$$

I'm tempted to write this as an answer to the question linked at the beginning of this question, but I'm not 100% sure it's true.

> **Question.** Is the length of the multilinear cross product of $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ given by $$|x_1 \times \cdots \times x_n| = \sqrt{\det([x_1,\ldots,x_n]^\top [x_1,\ldots,x_n])}\ ?$$
>
> If so, how do we prove this?
>
> If not, what is the correct formula?

Comment: This is the correct formula, and in fact this is part of what Brown and Gray take as part of the definition of ($n$-fold) cross product in their paper classifying such operations. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02564418

Comment: @Travis, thanks. That's an amazing article!

Comment: You're welcome. And it really is---cross products are really a surprisingly rich subject.

Comment: I should clarify: The paper of Brown and Gray classify cross products over arbitrary fields (not of characteristic $2$). The special case of cross products over $\Bbb R^n$ was worked out earlier by Eckmann and Whitehead, using rather different techniques.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I show the proof for $n=3,$ it can easily be extended to any $n\in\mathbb{N}.$

Let $u=x\times y\times z$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix} & & & \\ u & x & y & z \\ & & & \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{4\times 4}.$ Applying [Cramer's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule), we find
$$
A^T\cdot u = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \det(A)
$$
On the other hand, we have $u=A\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}.$ Therefore, 
$$
A^TA\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\cdot \det(A)
$$
Note that $$A^TA = 
\begin{pmatrix} u^Tu & 0 \\ 0 & \left[x,y,z\right]^T\left[x,y,z\right] \end{pmatrix}
$$
Therefore, we get
$$ u^Tu = \det(A) = \sqrt{\det(A^T)\det(A)} = \sqrt{\det(A^TA)}
=\sqrt{u^T u \cdot \det(\left[x,y,z\right]^T\left[x,y,z\right])}
$$
Now we can divide by $\sqrt{u^Tu}$ on both sides and get the desired result.

Comment: Cool! Never realized Cramer's rule was actually good for something :)

Comment: Do you know of any other applications of Cramer's rule?

Comment: @goblin I cannot come up with anything at the moment.