# Finding Orthogonal Basis For $W^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

> Let $w=(1,2,3,1)$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R^4}$ find an orthogonal basis for $W^{\perp}$

So of course we can use Gram-Schmidt process, but I would like to try it without, If we find The null space of $\langle(1,2,3,1),(a,b,c,d)\rangle=0$ we will get a basis which is not orthogonal, can we create more terms on $a,b,c,d$ to make the basis orthogonal?

Answer (score 1):

We are looking for three orthogonal vectors $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}$ such that $$a+2b+3c+d = 0.\tag 1$$ We can find two of them very easily by ensuring that $c,d=0$ in the first vector and $a,b=0$ in the second vector. For example, $v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\-3\end{bmatrix}$ lie in $W^{\perp}$. For the third vector, you may find a vector that satisfies $(1)$ then remove its projections along $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Answer (score 1):

I would start as in [Math Lover's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2444788/finding-orthogonal-basis-for-w-perp#2444820). Then, I want to have a fourth vector which is orthogonal to$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\\1\end{bmatrix}\text{, to }\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\text{, and to }\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\-3\end{bmatrix}.$$In order to find such a vector, I would use the [$4$-dimensional cross-product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371022/cross-product-in-higher-dimensions/2371039#2371039).