Name of the inequality associated with the cross product
Problem: If there exist $a,b,c,x,y,z \in ℝ$ such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=x^2+y^2+z^2=2$, then find the range of values that the following expression can take;
$$E=(b^2+c^2)x^2+(c^2+a^2)y^2+(a^2+b^2)z^2-2(ab xy+bc yz+ca zx)$$
I solved this problem by forming two vectors $\vec{r_1}=x \hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k}$ and $\vec{r_2}=a \hat{i}+ b \hat{j} + c \hat{k}$ and using the bounds on their cross product;
$$0≤|\vec{r_1} \times \vec{r_2}|≤|\vec{r_1}||\vec{r_2}|$$
And upon solving the $3 \times 3$ determinant for the cross product, and determining the modulus of the newly obtained vector, I got the square root of $E$. Hence, $E \in [0,4]$ where the extreme bounds are attained when $ax+by+cz=0$ in case of the maximum and $\dfrac{a}{x}=\dfrac{b}{y}=\dfrac{c}{z}$ in case of the minimum.
I know that when we use the inequality for the dot product in $3$ dimensions, it is basically just a special case of the Cauchy Schwarz inequality. What is the name of this inequality for the cross product and how can it be generalized to $n$ variables?

I wonder what you mean by "generalized to n variables". Maybe you mean to generalize the cross product to $n$ dimensions by saying it is an operation which takes in $n-1$ vectors and produces a vector that is perpendicular to each one.  And the magnitude of the cross product of n-1 vectors is the volume of the higher-dimensional parallelogram that they determine. Then, of course still the "cross-product-inequality" holds. For conceptualizing this idea, you may want to read Eric Korman's answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/186000  , or other answers to the related question.

yes, that is basically what I was looking for, thanks a lot!
