Why do we have 2 types of products for vectors?
Why is it that we have two types of products for vectors ? Why do we have one scalar product and one vector product? If we were concerned with the magnitude of the product, wouldn't it be easier to take the cross product and then find its magnitude? What is the point of having two types of vector products? I read online that "one product cannot give both quantities" but I am unable to understand why.
For context, I am in my final year of highschool learning about vectors and also try to learn about their applications in machine learning and AI for college, and the definitions of these products do not satisfy me.

As you'll see from your text, these are very different sorts of products.  The dot product produces a scalar, and the cross product produces another vector.  And they have very different applications.

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that they have different applications, and the classical cross product is only for $\mathbb R^3$

In addition to Tanner's comment, note that just because a scalar product does not generally give a magnitude anyway: for example, its value might be -7.

I suggest you see this article How to ask a good question

Those "two" products arise from the quaternionic product. They correspond to the scalar and the vector part of the quaternionic product. I recommend you read about Geometric (Clifford) Algebra to understand the root reason.

Every $\mathbb{R}^n$ has the dot product but almost none of these have a cross product. So a more precise question is why $\mathbb{R}^3$ has a cross product when (most) others don't. For more in this vein, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185991/is-the-vector-cross-product-only-defined-for-3d

We also have exterior products and geometric products of vectors. Why would we restrict ourselves to have just one product? Are you aware that mathematical concepts precede mathematical formalizations?

@JohnDouma I am not aware of such a statement. I think a better way to ask my question would be why can't we have a single product which can perform all these functions at once, and why is it necessary to have these different types of products for vectors.

If you are interested in machine learning, I think you will find that the dot product is widely used and the cross product is almost never used. This is because in ML you are usually dealing with vectors that have a lot more than three dimensions and the cross product is not even defined.

What these "products" have in common is that they are a mapping (let us denote it by $f$) from $\mathbb{R}^3$ into some vector space with the property that, for all vectors $x,y,z$ and scalars $\alpha$, we have
$$f(x+z,y)=f(x,y)+f(z,y)$$
$$f(\alpha x,y)=\alpha f(x,y)$$
$$f(x,y+z)=f(x,y)+f(x,z)$$
$$f(x,\alpha y)=\alpha f(x,y)$$
When these conditions are satisfied, we call $f$ bilinear.
There are many such bilinear mappings. Some of them are called "product", but only because they are very important or interesting, and not because there is any hard mathematical property that distinguishes a "product" from a normal bilinear function.
In more advanced mathematics, there are also other bilinear mappings that are called "product", e.g. tensor product, symmetric product, wedge product. They are a bit different in that their target spaces are pretty difficult to define, but still I would say it's misguided to think of scalar product and cross product as "the" two products for vectors.
It's different for e.g. the product of real numbers, because we usually see multiplication as an integral part of what it means to be a real number. In contrast, while the scalar product is of course very important, it is still possible to do a lot of linear algebra without ever mentioning it.

If we were concerned with the magnitude of the product, wouldn't it be easier to take the cross product and then find its magnitude?

Exactly. If we are concerned with the magnitude of the cross product, we can just take the magnitude of the cross product. :) It's neither true that the cross product lacks a magnitude, nor that the scalar product is a magnitude.

I read online that "one product cannot give both quantities" but I am unable to understand why.

Without additional context, I would say that you can't understand it because it is nonsense.

and the definitions of these products do not satisfy me.

That's perfectly normal. They are on their own pretty unintuitive. You gradually get intuition about them by learning about theorems in which they appear.

Thank you so much for your answer! Upon further thinking I think I have identified a better way to frame my question, and I would appreciate it if you could have a look at it.
Why can't we have a single product which can perform all these functions at once, and why is it necessary to have these different types of products for vectors?

@trippy07 What functions would that be? My point is that you can't answer that, whence your question makes no sense. (But it is a very natural question to ask in the final year of high school.)

The functions I am talking about are providing both a direction and a magnitude to a product of vectors, why is it that a product cannot give us both.

@PratixitTripathy It's just not true that the scalar product is the magnitude and the cross product is the direction of some entity that is "the product" of two vectors. So it's pointless to ask why.

So I have something fundamentally wrong in my perception of products?

@PratixitTripathy Yes, I think so. I've also added a bit to my answer.

+1 for your last sentence. When people agonize over trying to understand the intuition behind a definition, the end of their agony often comes from a deeper understanding of how that definition is applied.

The two products are very different. The cross product (vector product) is only defined in 3D and 7D. Given two vectors, the cross product gives the vector that is orthogonal to the two vectors. The dot product (scalar product), is defined the product of the magnitudes of the two vectors and the cosine of the angle between them. The scalar product is NOT equal to the magnitude of the cross product.

Only defined in 3D and 7D since we  have quarternions and octonions.
